# ios webrtc virtual background and filter

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, flutter, webrtc

i want to change the videosource from the rtccameravideocapture to remove background or add filter. and the method i do is to change the initwithdelegate to the class i create called myvideosourcefilter, so i can't use the didcapturevideoframe method , but the question is didcapturevideoframe method never goes in , what do i do wrong, the result i that i can initwithmyvideosource class, but i can't use the didcapturevideoframe method , i wonder what did i do wrong.

```
MyVideoSourceFilter *filter = [[MyVideoSourceFilter alloc] initWithSource:videoSource];
     self.videoCapturer = [[RTCCameraVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:filter];
     self.videoCapturer.delegate = filter;
```

i want to override the didcapturevideoframe method , but the didcaptureframe method never goes in , what did i do wrong or what should i add

`MyVideoSourceFilter *filter = [[MyVideoSourceFilter alloc] initWithSource:videoSource];      self.videoCapturer = [[RTCCameraVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:filter];      self.videoCapturer.delegate = filter;`

```
- (instancetype)initWithSource:(RTCVideoSource *)source {
    NSLog(@"init with source ");
    self = [super init];
    self.videoSource = source;
    //if (self = [super init]) {


    //}
    return self;
}

- (void)capturer:(RTCVideoCapturer *)capturer didCaptureVideoFrame:(RTCVideoFrame *)frame {
     NSLog(@"did capture video frame ");

   if (self.videoSource != nil) {
        [self.videoSource capturer:capturer didCaptureVideoFrame:frame];
    }else{
         NSLog(@"self.source = nil ");
    }
}
```

and the method i do is to change the initwithdelegate to the class i create called myvideosourcefilter, so i can't use the didcapturevideoframe method , but the question is didcapturevideoframe method never goes in , what do i do wrong, the result i that i can initwithmyvideosource class, but i can't use the didcapturevideoframe method , i wonder what did i do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `filter` variable is not kept referenced after the function has finished running, like the `videoCapturer` variable it is kept referenced in self. Let's do that and I think it will work. Now define the `filter` variable in the header file like `videoCapturer` and edit the code as follows:

```objectivec
self.filter = [[MyVideoSourceFilter alloc] initWithSource:videoSource];
self.videoCapturer = [[RTCCameraVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:filter];
self.videoCapturer.delegate = self.filter;
```